# background-size in shorthand background property (CSS3)

Tags: css

I'm trying to mix `background-image` and `background-size` properties in a shorthanded `background` property. Based on [**W3C documentation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) `background-size` should come after `background-position` property separated with an slash(`/`).

W3C example:

> ```
> p { background: url("chess.png") 40% / 10em gray
>        round fixed border-box; }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> p {
>     background-color: gray;
>     background-position: 40% 50%;
>     background-size: 10em 10em;
>     background-repeat: round round;
>     background-clip: border-box;
>     background-origin: border-box;
>     background-attachment: fixed;
>     background-image: url(chess.png) }
> ```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) says same thing. I also found [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) and [this](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/) article about shorthand CSS3 background property explaining this.

But this is not working! It also is not clear how to make a shorthand `background` property when `background-size` and `background-position` have two different values for `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` or same thing for `background-size`. It's not clear how the slash(`/`) takes place? [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/G67Ej/) is not working in my Chrome 15.

Example I tried to make a shorthand is this CSS code:

```
div {  
    background: url(http://www.placedog.com/125/125) 
        0 0 /  150px 100px 
        repeat no-repeat 
        fixed border-box padding-box blue;      
    height: 300px;
    width:360px;    
    border: 10px dashed magenta;  
}
```

## A cleaner example

*This is working* ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsbU/))

```
 body{
        background-image:url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
        background-position:200px 100px;
        background-size:600px 400px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

*This is not working* ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsbU/7/))

```
body{
    background:url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) 200px 100px/600px 400px no-repeat;
}
```

*This is not working too*([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsbU/8/))

```
body{
    background:url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) 200px/400px 100px/600px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Beware of Safari not supporting background-size shorthand! Safari doesn't support it! Put your background-size separate from your background to keep Safari from choking on it!

Comment: [MDN shows an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Here's another simpler example with a working image: http://jsfiddle.net/hspead40/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

1. Your jsfiddle uses `background-image` instead of `background`
2. It seems to be a case of "not supported by this browser yet".

This works in Opera : http://jsfiddle.net/ZNsbU/5/
But it doesn't work in FF5 nor IE8. (yay for outdated browsers :D )

### Code :

```css
body {
  background:url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) 400px 200px / 600px 400px no-repeat;
}
```

You could do it like this :

```css
body {
    background:url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) 400px 400px no-repeat;
    background-size:20px 20px
}
```

Which works in FF5 and Opera but not in IE8.

Comment: Do you think it is not a browser support issue?

Comment: I'm just wondered what is the right specification for CSS3 `background`?

Comment: It's what the W3C defined, exactly like you have in your question or my Code example. It's just not implemented in all browsers yet.

Comment: It's not working in Chrome Canary. I can't believe it's not implemented yet.

Comment: Selected as answer for this part: *It seems to be a case of "not supported by this browser yet" case.*

Comment: Android's built-in browser also still doesn't support background-size in shorthand background!

Answer (score 16):

You can do as

```
 body{
        background:url('equote.png'),url('equote.png');
        background-size:400px 100px,50px 50px;
    }
```

Comment: This is what helped me the most; I didn't know you could split the background size declarations with a comma, one for each url above it.

Answer (score 9):

Just a note for reference: I was trying to do shorthand like so:

```
background: url('../images/sprite.png') -312px -234px / 355px auto no-repeat;
```

but iPhone Safari browsers weren't showing the image properly with a fixed position element. I didn't check with a non-fixed, because I'm lazy. I had to switch the css to what's below, being careful to put background-size ***after*** the background property. If you do them in reverse, the background reverts the background-size to the original size of the image. So generally I would avoid using the shorthand to set background-size.

```
background: url('../images/sprite.png') -312px -234px no-repeat;
background-size: 355px auto;
```

Comment: Same here on Android 4.1.2 Stock Browser

Answer (score 2):

**try out like this**

```
body {
   background: #fff url("!--MIZO-PRO--!") no-repeat center 15px top 15px/100px;
     }


/* 100px is the background size */
```

Answer (score -7):

You will have to use vendor prefixes to support different browsers and therefore can't use it in shorthand.

```
body { 
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. I don't *have to* use vendor prefix if I don't want support old browsers

Comment: This vendor prefixes still work and some browsers may only recently have dropped it.