# I can't add a CSS "background-size" value to "background" property's value

Tags: css, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [background-size in shorthand background property (CSS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864448/background-size-in-shorthand-background-property-css3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 Document</title>
<style>
    div {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        background: red url(https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png) 50% 50% cover no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<div></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gu9fh

I wanna define a CSS `background-size` property with value `cover`. But I don't tend to write a single `background-size` property. I wanna combine it to the `background` property. But the background doesn't be displayed.

How can I add a CSS `background-size` value `cover` to the `background` property's value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also what hasn't been noted yet is that not all browsers (including Chrome) supports the new CSS3 shorthand for background.

For better support you probably should just use the `background-size` property separately as most new browsers support it that way.

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red url(https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The code above works in both FireFox and Chrome while the shorthand does not.

For a demo and proper attribute ordering see the link below.

See [Dev - Opera - Background Shorthand](http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/backgrounds/background-shorthand.html)

Comment: Thanks again for pointing that out. What version of Chrome are you using? The shorthand appears to work fine in Chrome 21 OSX.

Comment: But should also point out that the question specifically asked how to implement this with `cover` applied using the `background` property alone. I still voted up though

Comment: Thanks yeah yours and others were correct and upvoted :D  Yeah I  thought the poster should know before using that its not well supported. I am on Chrome 20 but an update is available haha... the new one probably fixes this but still not supported in FireFox yet...  Not sure about other Webkit browsers or Opera though.

Answer (score 6):

When using the shorthand property, the `background-size` value must be paired with `background-position` and separated by a `/`

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/5jJfQ/

See the documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#properties7

Comment: Not all browsers support the CSS3 shorthand for backgrounds yet.  Your answer does not render in Chrome or FireFox.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the arguments for `background` was off. *repeat* should go before *position*. Then as jrrdnx noted, *size* and *position* should be separated by a `/`

```
background: red url(https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png) no-repeat 50% 50%/cover;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gu9fh/5/

And a good reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background

**EDIT:** As PJH noted, the shorthand for *position/size* is not yet supported in Firefox or Safari. You simply need to set the `background-size` on it's own.

```
background: red url(https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
```

And updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gu9fh/6/

Comment: This is also correct by standards but will not be supported in a lot of browsers still.  Chrome and FireFox cannot render it for starters.

Comment: This **does** work in Chrome, but you are correct, not in Firefox or Safari. Updated, thanks

Comment: Yeah I am on Chrome 20 still and it wasn't working on mine.  Still no FireFox though.