# Can you declare the background-size in shorthand for the background:

Tags: css

I am used to writing out my background properties in shorthand like so...

```
background: #444 url(hero.jpg) no-repeat center right;
```

Is there anyway I can incorporate the background-size property into my shorthand? What about some of the new css3 background properties? Are they are able to be written in shorthand?

Comment: Did you see this question? [background-size in shorthand background property (CSS3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864448/background-size-in-shorthand-background-property-css3)

Comment: No I didn't thanks for sending along

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The full CSS3 syntax is:

```
background: color position/size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;
```

**Note:** If one of the properties in the shorthand declaration is the background-size property, you must use a / (slash) to separate it from the background-postion property, e.g. background:url(smiley.gif) 10px 20px/50px 50px; will result in a background image, positioned 10 pixels from the left, 20 pixels from the top, and the size of the image will be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.