# CSS3 - Use part of an image for background

Tags: css

I want to use some images as backgrounds but I have no control over the images. If the images are 500px x 500px , is it possible with just CSS3 to scale the image down to 200px x 200px and then only use 100px x 100px from the center?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this with some images and  your code.

Comment: It is possible to resize images in CSS, yes. However there are already several questions regarding this and this kind of information is pretty easily accessible just by searching it. Try adding `width:100%; height:auto;` to your div's CSS and the image should resize beautifully.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864448/background-size-in-shorthand-background-property-css3) it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to close if you wish

Comment: No problem - I should have researched more carefully on this one. I would delete but there are already answers.

Comment: @tommyd456: If you yourself feel that it is a dupe, please feel free to unaccept, remove the vote and delete it.I wouldn't mind :)

Comment: I will delete but my vote is locked in on @renzz17 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-size: 200px 200px;
background-position: center; 
background-image: 'your image here';
}
```