# What is / in CSS?

Tags: css

```
background: url(image) 0 / cover fixed;
```

Why is there:

- A `0` (zero)?
- A `/` (forward slash)?

What does that mean/do in CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864448/background-size-in-shorthand-background-property-css3

Comment: This is shorthand css

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know what to search for to find the asnwer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this CSS font shorthand syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-font-shorthand-syntax-mean)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a shorthand of specifying the background image for a html page. Completely equivalent to:

```
background: url(image);
background-margin: 0
background-size: cover;
background-position: fixed;
```